# How can I get all the rows from master table and relevent row from the detail table in MS-SQL?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, select

I am using MS-SQL and I am trying to write a query which fetches rows from the master table and related rows from the detail table. Now, the thing I want is that it must **only** fetch the first row from the master table and related field from the detail tables should be blank in that first row, now if there are related rows found in the detail tables, they must be shown in the separate rows. I have been trying using the following query but it is not giving the desired result.

```
SELECT 
      DISTINCT 
      ProductMaster.ProductMasterID, ProductMaster.ProductName,
      ProductMaster.SubCategoryID, SubCategory.SubCategoryName,
      ProductBrandAndType.ProductBranAndTypeID, ProductBrandAndType.ProductType,
      ProductBrandAndType.Brand, ProductMaster.ProductDesc, 
      ProductMaster.ReOrderLevel 
FROM 
   ProductBrandAndType 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
   Inward 
ON ProductBrandAndType.ProductBranAndTypeID = Inward.ProductBrandAndTypeID 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
   ProductMaster 
ON Inward.ProductID = ProductMaster.ProductMasterID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   SubCategory 
ON ProductMaster.SubCategoryID = SubCategory.SubCategoryID 
ORDER BY 
      ProductMaster.ProductName, 
      ProductBrandAndType.ProductType, 
      ProductBrandAndType.Brand;
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Regards

Sikandar

Comment: This is effectively presentation, and is much better dealt with in e.g. a report builder/formatter than in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following query worked.

```
SELECT     dbo.ProductMaster.ProductMasterID, dbo.ProductMaster.ProductName, dbo.ProductMaster.SubCategoryID, dbo.ProductMaster.ProductDesc, 
                      dbo.ProductMaster.ReOrderLevel, null as ProductBrandAndTypeID,  
                      null AS Type, null as Brand
FROM         dbo.ProductBrandAndType RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Inward ON dbo.ProductBrandAndType.ProductBranAndTypeID = dbo.Inward.ProductBrandAndTypeID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.ProductMaster ON dbo.Inward.ProductID = dbo.ProductMaster.ProductMasterID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.SubCategory ON dbo.ProductMaster.SubCategoryID = dbo.SubCategory.SubCategoryID
UNION 
SELECT     dbo.ProductMaster.ProductMasterID, dbo.ProductMaster.ProductName, dbo.ProductMaster.SubCategoryID, dbo.ProductMaster.ProductDesc, 
                      dbo.ProductMaster.ReOrderLevel, dbo.ProductBrandAndType.ProductBranAndTypeID,  
                      dbo.ProductBrandAndType.ProductType, dbo.ProductBrandAndType.Brand
FROM         dbo.ProductBrandAndType RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Inward ON dbo.ProductBrandAndType.ProductBranAndTypeID = dbo.Inward.ProductBrandAndTypeID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.ProductMaster ON dbo.Inward.ProductID = dbo.ProductMaster.ProductMasterID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.SubCategory ON dbo.ProductMaster.SubCategoryID = dbo.SubCategory.SubCategoryID                      
ORDER BY ProductName;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just what the first row from the ProductMaster. Then you can do something like this:

```
;WITH CTE
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ProductMaster.ProductMasterID) AS RowNbr,
        ProductMaster.ProductName,
        ProductMaster.SubCategoryID,
        ProductMaster.ProductDesc, 
        ProductMaster.ReOrderLevel 
    FROM
        ProductMaster
)
SELECT
      ProductMaster.ProductMasterID, 
      ProductMaster.ProductName,
      ProductMaster.SubCategoryID, 
      SubCategory.SubCategoryName,
      ProductBrandAndType.ProductBranAndTypeID, 
      ProductBrandAndType.ProductType,
      ProductBrandAndType.Brand, 
      ProductMaster.ProductDesc, 
      ProductMaster.ReOrderLevel 
FROM 
   ProductBrandAndType 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Inward 
    ON ProductBrandAndType.ProductBranAndTypeID = Inward.ProductBrandAndTypeID 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN CTE AS ProductMaster
    ON Inward.ProductID = ProductMaster.ProductMasterID
    AND RowNbr=1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN SubCategory 
    ON ProductMaster.SubCategoryID = SubCategory.SubCategoryID 
ORDER BY 
    ProductMaster.ProductName, 
    ProductBrandAndType.ProductType, 
    ProductBrandAndType.Brand;
```